# fetch from two tables with a single query having multiple time range

Tags: php, mysql

i have two table `report` and `report1`

`report` table

```
id   user    dt
1    a  2014-06-23 05:30:00
2    b  2014-06-23 06:30:00
3    c  2014-06-23 06:31:00
4    d  2014-06-23 07:30:00
```

to generate a report like this with multiple date range i did

```
range             count     
06:31:00-07:30:00   2
5:30:00-6:30:00     2
```

`file.php`

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT CASE
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '05:30:00' and '06:30:00' and  DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y:%m:%d')=DATE(CURDATE())
            THEN '5:30:00-6:30:00'
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '06:31:00' and '07:30:00' and DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y:%m:%d')=DATE(CURDATE())
            THEN '06:31:00-07:30:00'
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '07:31:00' and '08:30:00' and DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y:%m:%d')=DATE(CURDATE())
            THEN '07:30:00-08:30:00'
    ELSE NULL
    END AS TimeRange,
    COUNT(*) as number
FROM report
GROUP BY TimeRange
HAVING TimeRange IS NOT NULL");

echo'<html>
<head>
<title>Count User Info TimeWise</title>
</head>
<h1>Count User</h1>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1">

 <tr>
 <th>range</th>
 <th>count</th>
 <th>Apps Count</th>';

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {
echo  "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['TimeRange'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['number'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
echo "</table>";      
echo "</html>";
?>
```

now i want to generate the report adding one more column which will fetch from another table `report1`

```
range             count         countapps
06:31:00-07:30:00   2             count from report1
5:30:00-6:30:00     2             count from report1
```

`report1` table

```
user    dt
a     2014-06-26 05:30:00
b     2014-06-26 06:00:00
```

how can i do this in a single query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would use your current query as a sub query and join that against the other table (as your current query generates the timerange name that the other table is keyed on).

Something like this, although you would need to add the date to the sub query as well (not sure what date you want to join on - are all records from the same date?):-

```
SELECT sub0.TimeRange, sub0.number, report1.`count`
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '05:30:00' and '06:30:00'
                THEN '5:30:00-6:30:00'
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '06:31:00' and '07:30:00'
                THEN '06:31:00-07:30:00'
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '07:31:00' and '08:30:00'
                THEN '07:30:00-08:30:00'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS TimeRange,
        COUNT(*) as number
    FROM report
    GROUP BY TimeRange
    HAVING TimeRange IS NOT NULL
) sub0
LEFT OUTER JOIN report1
ON report1.range = sub0.TimeRange
```

EDIT - bit clunky, but think something like this would do it:-

```
SELECT sub0.TimeRange, sub0.number, COUNT(*) AS countapps
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '05:30:00' and '06:30:00'
                THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '05:30:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '06:31:00' and '07:30:00'
                THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '06:31:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '07:31:00' and '08:30:00'
                THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '07:30:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
            ELSE NULL
        END AS StartRange,
        CASE
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '05:30:00' and '06:30:00'
                THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '06:30:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '06:31:00' and '07:30:00'
                THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '07:30:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '07:31:00' and '08:30:00'
                THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '08:30:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
            ELSE NULL
        END AS EndRange,
        CASE
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '05:30:00' and '06:30:00'
                THEN '05:30:00-06:30:00'
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '06:31:00' and '07:30:00'
                THEN '06:31:00-07:30:00'
            WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '07:31:00' and '08:30:00'
                THEN '07:30:00-08:30:00'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS TimeRange,
        COUNT(*) as number
    FROM report
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y:%m:%d')=DATE(CURDATE())
    GROUP BY StartRange, EndRange, TimeRange
    HAVING TimeRange IS NOT NULL
) sub0
LEFT OUTER JOIN report1
ON report1.dt BETWEEN sub0.StartRange AND sub0.EndRange
GROUP BY sub0.TimeRange, sub0.number
```

Comment: How in more detail do you want to join report1? When the date and time match the date and start time? Or just where the time is within the time range?

Comment: just adding this `and DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y:%m:%d')=DATE(CURDATE())` in each line to fetch every record between time-range and currentdate.i have edited my question with these lines.

Comment: i tested your code but if a value in countapps column(report1.dt) is not found in a given time-range it showing the previous value from the previous time-range and looping it through all lower time ranges

Comment: It shouldn't do. I can't see how that SQL can do that (although it would be easy to do that in a script processing the results). Could you put up an example set of tables and data on SQL fiddle to demonstrate it please?